# Prestashop 1.7.5.0 Live server issue

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I'm using prestashop 1.7.5.0 its work fine in my localhost. But hosted in the live server it will not work.

I'm  already tried this https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-migrate-a-prestashop-site-from-local-host-to-live-server/

Comment: Please be specific in what you are asking.. Please specify the exact error codes and environment, in order for us to help you..

Comment: 500 Server Error hosted in godaddy

Comment: try to remove .htaccess and desactivate seo rewrite from dbb, also in config/defines.inc.php activate errors to see the problem